# How to Load HTML Page Using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load an external html file using JQuery. But, the following code does not work:

```
<!-- JQuery Code-->
                 <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
     
        
        $("#div1").load("header.html");
      
    });
                  </script>
            </head>
         <body>
          
             <div id="div1"></div>
    
          </body>
```

Comment: Assuming you've referenced jQuery.js in your page, and the path to `header.html` is correct, then what you have should function correctly. As such we need more information than simply 'it doesn't work'. Open devtools and inspect the network tab to see what the result of your AJAX request is and debug from there.

Comment: header,html is in the same folder

Comment: Ok, and what about the output from devtools?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/ibnat/MyProjects/Xeo/header.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: That's your problem - you can't make AJAX requests to the local file system - it would be a massive security flaw if that was possible. You need to run your code on a webserver.

Comment: See this question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10752055/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks....the issue was with the local server....your solution has worked...thanks

Comment: Glad you got it solved. I'd suggest deleting this question in that case, as what you asked had nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the following code with debug !! to see what is your problem

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $("#div1").load( "header.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Nothing is showing

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but note that debugging instructions are not answers.

Comment: you need to check your console,
if its having ready at least we know that you know how to load Jquery
then you need to log response to see what was the result of your request to head

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is nothing on page we can depend on it to answer i thought it will help him to debug the problem

Comment: Which is why we have comments.